# Keep attempted URL parameter after a redirection

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my Angular project, I just implemented Amazon Cognito Hosted UI to handle my sign in like this:

[image: Amazon Cognito Hosted UI]

Now, when my users click on my sign in button, they are redirected to another URL like `https://[domain].amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/&response_type=code&client_id=[some id]` to sign in and redirected back to my Angular URL in case of success.

Before implementing that, I had a simple sign-in page combined with an authguard to protect my routes which **stored the attempted URL and redirected back after sign in**. And because I was only on Angular, everything worked smoothly.

Now, because of the functioning of the Cognito Hosted UI, the attempted URL parameter is lost when my user is redirected to the Hosted UI.

**My question:**
Is there a way to keep my attempted URL parameter even with this redirection?

**More informations**

I don't have a login component anymore because it is handle by Cognito Hosted UI.

This is an excerpt of the component which call my Cognito Hosted UI :

**navbar.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  [...]

  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected localeId: string,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private usersService: UsersService
  ) { }

  [...]

  signIn() {
    this.authService.signIn();
  }
```

}

**navbar.component.html**

```
<div class="navbar-item" *appShowIfSignedIn="false">
  <a class="button" (click)="signIn()">Sign in</a>
</div>
```

Here is an excerpt of my AuthService :

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  private url = 'https://' + '[domain].auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com' + '/login?redirect_uri=' + 'http://localhost:4200/' + '&response_type=' + 'code' + '&client_id=' + '[some id]';

  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private authStore: AuthStore
  ) {
    Hub.listen('auth', this, 'AuthCodeListener');
  }

  onHubCapsule(capsule: any) {
    const { channel, payload } = capsule;
    if (channel === 'auth' && payload.event === 'signIn') {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.currentAuthenticatedUser().subscribe(
          (user: any) => {
            const isSignedIn = true;
            const accessToken = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken;
            const sub = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload['sub'];
            this.authStore.update({
              signedIn: isSignedIn,
              accessToken: accessToken,
              sub: sub
            });
          }
        );
      });
    }
  }

  signIn() {
    window.location.assign(this.url);
  }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post your login component ts / authentication comoponent ts here, so that we can  help ?

Comment: this is just the service..Component is missing

Comment: What do you mean by component? You mean the component who call my auth service?

Comment: exactly..The components who uses your auth service

Comment: I added my component. Basically, my navigation component call the url with a button, I am redirected to the hosted UI URL (out of Angular) and after coming back to Angular in the root url `http://localhost:4200/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it by simply store my attempted URL parameter in my local storage.

That way, I can retrieve my attempted URL parameter even after be redirected back from the Hosted UI.